# Inner switch text MaterializeCSS

Tags: css, materialize

I have a simple Materialize switch element and I want to add some text inside.

MaterializeCSS example switch:

[image: Current switch]

This is the code:

```
<div class="switch">
<label>
  Off
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="lever"></span>
  On
</label>
```

Desired switch:

https://codepen.io/chiandet/pen/raNKbE

Its enough by just getting some text inside the switch and making it square; is it possible?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're linking to a demo that does, and looks, exactly as you want; what help do you need, specifically? Where have your own attempts failed, what went wrong, where are your own attempts?

Comment: @DavidThomas I tried to insert that same solution into my project but clearly has a bunch of declarations that crash with MaterializeCSS library.
I do not know how or which element I have to change or add to insert the inner text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/55L52yww/190/

HTML

```
<div class="switch">
<label>
<input type="checkbox" class="upsellActiveToggle" checked="checked"><span class="lever">
<span class="off">Off</span>
<span class="on">On</span>
</span>
</label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.switch label input[type=checkbox]:checked+.lever {
    background-color: #c3ccd9;
    padding: 3px 0 0 10px;
}
.switch label .lever {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 60px;
    height: 21px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.38);
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
    transition: background 0.3s ease;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 16px;
}
.switch label .lever:before, .switch label .lever:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    border-radius: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: -1px;
    transition: left 0.3s ease, background .3s ease, box-shadow 0.1s ease, transform .1s ease;
}
.switch label input[type=checkbox]:checked+.lever:before, .switch label input[type=checkbox]:checked+.lever:after {
    left: 37px;
}
.switch label input[type=checkbox]+.lever span.off, .switch label input[type=checkbox]+.lever span.off {
    display: none;
}
.switch label input[type=checkbox]+.lever span.on, .switch label input[type=checkbox]+.lever span.on {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px 0 0 15px;
}

.switch label input[type=checkbox]:checked+.lever span.on, .switch label input[type=checkbox]:checked+.lever span.on {
    display: none;
}
.switch label input[type=checkbox]:checked+.lever span.off, .switch label input[type=checkbox]:checked+.lever span.off {
    display: inline-block;
}
.switch label input[type=checkbox]+.lever {
    background-color: #111;
    padding: 3px 0 0 15px;
}
```

You probably need to do some more styling to have what you actually need

Comment: Your switch is not square.

Comment: @Glubey , it's super square now :)

Comment: @KentV You are a genius!!; also I would like to make that Butt text disappear and appear another text when the switch switches, is it possible?

Comment: @Marcelo , there you go. Please see updated jsfiddle link

Comment: @KentV Awesome work Kent, that was exactly what I was looking for!